# Is it possible to stop a service through launchd if the service is started manually?

Tags: mac-osx, service, launchd, osx-mountain-lion, launchctl

I am using launchd to start mysql on boot, it is working fine. I am able to stop and start the service using 'launchctl unload' and 'launchctl load' commands. Also I am able to start the service by typing 'mysqld_safe' command in terminal. But, if I stop the service through 'launchctl stop' and then start the service through 'mysqld_safe' command, I am unable to stop the service through 'launchctl stop'. Is this possible? What I am doing wrong here?

My Plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>mysql.service</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/path/to/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
                <string>--defaults-file=/path/to/mysql/my.cnf</string>
                <string>--port=3306</string>
                <string>--socket=/path/to/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock</string>
                <string>--datadir=/path/to/mysql/data</string>
                <string>--log-error=/path/to/mysql/data/mysqld.log</string>
                <string>--pid-file=/path/to/mysql/data/mysqld.pid</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>KeepAlive</key>
       <false/>
       <key>UserName</key>
       <string>_mysql</string>
       <key>GroupName</key>
       <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/mysql_start.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/mysql_start.err</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Command used to start mysql through terminal is:

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/path/to/mysql/my.cnf --port=3306 --socket=/path/to/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --datadir=/path/to/mysql/data --pid-file=/path/to/mysql/data/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior. Issuing `launchctl stop` for a job which has not been loaded does not work.

Comment: To expand on this: if it wasn't started by the launchd daemon, it's not a launchd job can't be managed with `launchctl` -- it's just an independent process that happens to be running the same program that your launchd job would run.